# iOS Swift AddMob unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, admob

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 class MyPage: UIViewController ,UITextViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{
     var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
        fileprivate func createAndLoadInterstitial() {
            interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
            interstitial.delegate = self
            let request = GADRequest()
            // Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
            // an ad request is made.
            request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a" ]
            interstitial.load(request)
        }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}

extension MyPage:GADInterstitialDelegate{
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request succeeded.
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func interstitial(_ ad: GADInterstitial, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that an interstitial will be presented.
    func interstitialWillPresentScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillPresentScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
    func interstitialWillDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate the interstitial had been animated off the screen.
    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app
    /// (such as the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func interstitialWillLeaveApplication(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("interstitialWillLeaveApplication")
    }
}
```

And add Build Setting Debug And Release -ObjC

Is there anything else I can do besides this?

target iOS 11 Swift 4.1 Device - My Iphone 5S(iOS 11.1) , Simulator IphoneX (IOS 11.4)

stackTrace

```
GADDiskUsageStatisticsWithError + 11328
    17 MyApp                        0x100a78f6c GADDiskUsageStatisticsWithError + 3064
    18 MyApp                        0x100a78d98 GADDiskUsageStatisticsWithError + 2596
    19 MyApp                        0x100a51684 GADCategories_GADSlot_State + 5872
    20 MyApp                        0x100a08bac GADCategories_GADInterstitial_RewardBasedVideoAdGMSGAddition + 5980
    21 libdispatch.dylib              0x18105d088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    22 libdispatch.dylib              0x18105d048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    23 libdispatch.dylib              0x181069b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1016
    24 CoreFoundation                 0x181681eb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    25 CoreFoundation                 0x18167fa8c __CFRunLoopRun + 2012
    26 CoreFoundation                 0x18159ffb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    27 GraphicsServices               0x183437f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
    28 UIKit                          0x18ab742f4 UIApplicationMain + 208
    29 MyApp                        0x1007992e4 main (AppDelegate.swift:11)
    30 libdyld.dylib                  0x1810c256c start + 4
```

if i just load MyPage raise this exception

This is my problem.

I followed the example and followed it. Why not?

[image]

Comment: so what's your problem exactly?

Comment: @Hoven Add StackTrace

Comment: **WARNING**: Try to avoid posting *real* IDs in your question.

Comment: @AhmadF not real IDs this is google Test AD IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `interstitial.delegate = self` will Fix your problem

See [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial) for more Details

Comment: add `interstitial.delegate = self` and  `GADInterstitialDelegate` return same exception

Comment: @Adam do you implemented  GADInterstitialDelegate methods in MyPage class?

Comment: @Adam I mean **interstitialDidReceiveAd** for example

Comment: did you set Other Linker Flags to -ObjC in build settings?

Comment: @Adam what is in AppDelegate.swift: line 11 ?

Comment: line 11 is just class `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

Comment: i tried examples https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob this is work but my same code not work

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and build it again or clear derived data or restart xcode?  I think your config not applied yet. Or maybe there is no need to add ObjC in build setting in their new release

Comment: reboot Mac but same error , Does importing FireBase in AppDelegate affect anything? , examples used `GoogleMobileAds` but i use fireBase Is it related to this?

Comment: I found only one difference from the example, I am Swift 4.1 and the example is 3.3

Comment: My problem is that LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist was a string.
Thank you for your help.